# Navigation Drawer disable backview when drawer open

Tags: android, onclick, navigation-drawer, android-navigation

I am getting a strage behaviour with my navigation drawer. I use a custom layout for it, containing not only the usual listview!

Whenever i click somehwere in the drawer section the rows from the behind listview are getting clicked. How can i disable that?

**SOLUTION:** 
just set `android:clickable="true"` on the parent layout in the drawer outside the listview and it all works fine.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Try getting your drawer layout to be focused.

Comment: i tried to set `focusableInTouchMode=true` not working unfortunatelly...

Comment: Thanks Adrian his answers worked perfectly for me android:clickable="true"   setting it to the parent layout which contains navigational menu items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your MainAcivty with the drawer content when it's open, to disable sending touch events to parent layout

```
getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set android:clickable="true" to the parent layout in the drawer section.